# Generating placeholder images with PHP like placedog.com and placekitten.com

Tags: php, image

Does anybody know where I could get started on generating images with the dimensions passed through a url.

I want something like this:

If the url is example.com/400/200 then an image using a certain library of images generated at 400px wide by 200px high.

I know how to generate images using imagecreate() but would want the image created to be one using a library of images, much like [placekitten.com](http://www.placekitten.com) and [placedog.com](http://www.placedog.com) do

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: What problem are you having?  Getting images?  Getting the dimensions from the URL?  Resizing the images?

Comment: You can get the url parameters. for example you have this url example.com/?width=400&height=200 and then you can get the value by GET method ($_GET['width']) and then use it to generate the image.

Comment: I basically want to create a script which will create images dependant on the url that is written, but don't know where to begin. I'd like it to be using a library of images. At the moment I can only get an image  to be generated with text and a background colour.

Answer (score 0):

PHP built-in library - GD
http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

You could do like upload X photos and mark in them coords of center of important part of pic and then storage it in MySQL with data like: min_width, min_height, max_width, max_height. This data would be boundries of rectangles that could be copied from original photo. And then query for every pics that could be used between min and max [width/height], and make from it image and select one from them random. You could also storage results so that it wouldn't change after each time you query for that size and much faster (also save smaller pic somewhere).

Comment: I'm not sure if that was sarcasm :p but what the hell..
As for your idea that it has so much directories - well i say it's wrong becouse it would need so many directories - it's just imposible to get every AxB. 

As for my idea - it could also just use bigger pic in higher res with boundries like i said and if it would need to be smaller - then just scale pic with coords down.

Answer (score 0):

You should check http://placehold.it/.

This service is free, customizable and since it is another domain then web page loads faster.

Otherwise there are some nice tutorials on GD library:

http://motyar.blogspot.com/2010/09/create-image-placeholder-with-php.html

Comment: I want to create my own version for a project at work, so it's not ideal using placehold.it - would be great if they made their script available

Comment: Then see the blog link i gave :)

Comment: Yes, that one is good, but how would I use images such as cats, dogs etc in that example. That is what I am having problems with.

Comment: Alright, my mistake - didnt read the questin so well.